# How do I use IBM Watson's Text-To-Speech with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nlp, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm making a simple app to try out Watson's TTS with the Unity SDK. The only problem I have is that there are almost no resources online to help with this pursuit. I found a piece of code online, but when I tried it with my app, it didn't work because it was deprecated. Almost all Text-To-Speech examples with watson use the namespace`IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.TextToSpeech.v1;`, which happens to be deprecated and unusable anymore.
I was wondering if anybody could help me figure out/ provide code or links that could help me figure out how to use Watson's TTS with Unity, that isn't deprecated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to watson? http://www.voicerss.org/sdk/dotnet.aspx works great with Unity for me

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk) you can download the dotnet standard sdk that should work with Unity, too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use API like from TensorFlow using the WWWForms class in unity for create a CRUD

Find more information in [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html)

Search for: how to use API in unity. there are many tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the examples in the API reference at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=unity

Answer (score 0):

something like this... you will need to authenticate your service or have your credentials in an env file.

```cs
public void Start()
{
    LogSystem.InstallDefaultReactors();

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechService();
    while (!textToSpeech.Credentials.HasIamTokenData())
        yield return null;

    Runnable.Run(Synthesize("Hello world!"));
}

public IEnumerator Synthesize(string text)
{
    byte[] synthesizeResponse = null;
    AudioClip clip = null;
    textToSpeech.Synthesize(
        callback: (DetailedResponse<byte[]> response, IBMError error) =>
        {
            synthesizeResponse = response.Result;
            clip = WaveFile.ParseWAV("myClip", synthesizeResponse);
            PlayClip(clip);
        },
        text: text,
        voice: "en-US_AllisonVoice",
        accept: "audio/wav"
    );

    while (synthesizeResponse == null)
        yield return null;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);
}
```